# AWK deletes dots

Tags: bash, awk

Everyone,

I have a question about awk. I have a file and need to print out some text. 
Input:

```
lunar 05.00.Hello
lunar 05.00.Mockingbird
lunar "/^05\\.00\\.hello\\.com$/"
lunar "/^05\\.00\\.stolen\\ Heart$/"
lunar "/^05\\.00\\.Reggie\\.Ton$/"

calendar "/^05\\.00\\.Reggie\\.Ton$/"
calendar "/^05\\.00\\.Rural\\.Ton$/"
montnly "/^05\\.00\\.hello\\.com$/"
```

output I want:

```
Hello
Mockingbird
hello.com
stolen Heart
Reggie.Ton
```

but using awk

```
grep 'lunar' names.txt | awk -F. '{print $3,$4 }' | sed 's/[\/$"]/''/g' |sort | uniq > file2.txt
```

I have this output:

```
Hello
Mockingbird
hello com
stolen Heart
Reggie Ton
```

I mean the dots disappeared. How can I change awk there? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a single `awk`:

```
awk -F. '/lunar/{gsub(/[\\\/$"]/, ""); print $3 ($4 == "" ? "" : FS $4)}' file
```

```
Hello
Mockingbird
hello.com
stolen Heart
Reggie.Ton
```

Comment: Excuse me, but could you help to understand this ( $4 != "" ? FS $4 : ""). I 've got rest part of code and searched before asking but can't understand what does this part of code.

Comment: `($4 != "" ? FS $4 : "")` adds `FS` and `$4` in output if `$4` is not empty. `?` is ternary operator so it takes `FS $4` when `$4 != ""` is true otherwise it just takes `""`.

Answer (score 2):

awk is not removing the dots. Since dot is your delimiter, there are no more dots in those strings. What you can do is add some formating with printf and print a dot between the strings. You will also have to add `\n` to put the new lines (implicit in print).

Also I had to add the if condition to take into account cases in which there is only one field. This is not very robust though, if you have more possibilities (you dont specify) I can help you to make it more general and robust.

```
grep 'lunar'  names.txt  | awk -F. '{if ($4!="") {printf("%s.%s\n",$3,$4)} else{ {printf("%s\n",$3)}}}' | sed 's/[\/$"]/''/g' |sort | uniq > file2.txt
```

Output:

```
Hello
Mockingbird
hello.com
stolen Heart
Reggie.Ton
```

Comment: when you see `grep|awk|sed`, very likely it is not written in a good way.

Comment: True. My idea is to keep is the closest the the OP's version so it's really something he/she can understand easily. Not sure if it's useful though.

Comment: Thank u for trying to keep the original version to make it clear for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do `grep|awk|sed....`

```
awk '/lunar/{gsub(/\\\\/,"");sub(/[$].*/,"");sub(/lunar[^a-zA-Z]*/,"");print}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{gsub(/["\\/^$]/,"")} sub(/^lunar .{6}/,"")' file
Hello
Mockingbird
hello.com
stolen Heart
Reggie.Ton
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following :

```
sed -n '/^lunar/{s@["/$\^]@@g;s/^lunar 05\.00\.//p}' | sort -u > file2.txt
```

It first filters over lines starting with "lunar", then removes the special characters we don't want in our output so that every line matches the same format, then removes the leading "lunar 05.00." from these lines and prints what remains.

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/QWa2cI).

Comment: Aaron, what if rows in my files start like - define flash_lunar|  define abc_lunar and so on, but I wanna sed every row with word lunar?

Comment: Remove the `^` from `/^lunar/`, it matches the start of the line.